# Ordering by negative numbers in sphinx

Tags: sphinx

Im implementing sphinx search engine into my site, thru SpinxSE, its all seems to be working okay, except for one of the sort methods I have on my site, which is "ranking", which can be a negative number. For some reason when I sort it in descending order from highest to lowest, negative numbers appear on top of the list as highest rated, and once it reaches positive numbers, it appears normally.

```
WHERE query='keyword;sort=attr_desc:v_rating;'
```

How can I put these negative rankings at the end of the list, after items ranked 0?

Comment: Is the field "v_rating" defined as "sql_attr_uint" in the configuration file?

Comment: yeah, it is. Should I switch to sql_attr_bigint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching the column to  sql_attr_bigint solved the issue.

Comment: This also requires removing old files and recreating index from scratch instead of using indexer to rotate files.